# Science fiction series, asteroid-like space ship looked like a flying superhero

Tags: story-identification, tv

This probably would have been either in the mid to late 70's or early 80's.  It might have been a Saturday morning show, and was live action.  The only thing I remember about it was one of the space ships in it looked, to me, a little like a flying superhero.  The ship itself was, IIRC, very rough on the surface, almost like it might have been carved out of an asteroid or something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "like a flying superhero" do you mean that the ship while clearly not humanoid resembled one in some fashion, or could the ship have been some sort of mecha/robot?

Comment: It wasn't a robot, just resembled a humanoid.  Very massive ship.

Comment: It MIGHT have been Jason of Star Command.

Answer (score 5):

You're thinking of [*Jason of Star Command*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_of_Star_Command), a low-budget, live-action Saturday morning television program produced between 1978 and 1981. *Jason* was itself a spin-off of an earlier program named [*Space Academy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Academy), and reused some of the sets, props, and spaceship models.

Jason and the good guys operated from Space Academy, a mobile base built into an asteroid:

[image: Space Academy]

The head bad guy was named Dragos. He had a ship called the "Dragonship", which was also built into an asteroid:

[image: Dragonship Head On] [image: Dragonship Profile]

[Youtube has the first episode of the series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bnevbnyRd0). The Dragonship makes an appearance around the 8:36 mark.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!